# How do I run my Android custom build type?

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio

So I am trying to get my project to generate a signed and aligned apk and run it on my phone all through the Android Studio IDE.

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias 'key'
        keyPassword 'pwd'
        storeFile file('..\\m-release-key.keystore')
        storePassword 'pwd'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        jniDebugBuild false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        runProguard false
        zipAlign true
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I build, all that is getting produced is a debug-unaligned.apk, whether I click on Run or Debug, I get the same thing. I can't see any setting for this in Build Configurations either. How can I tell Android Studio to use my release build type? What am I missing?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Choose the release build variant from the **Build Variants** tool window, as shown:

[image: IDE screenshot, showing Build Variants tool window]

Comment: View -> Tool Windows -> Build Variants